# How do I remove the Buttons from the UWP TimePicker

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I need to remove the bottom Buttons from the TimePicker-Controll Flyout.
This style does it, but I can't see where the magic happens:

```
<Style x:Key="TimePickerStyle1" TargetType="TimePicker">
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TimePickerForegroundThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TimePicker">
                <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="0">
                    <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                          FlowDirection="{TemplateBinding FlowDirection}"
                                          FontWeight="{ThemeResource TimePickerHeaderThemeFontWeight}"
                                          Foreground="{ThemeResource TimePickerHeaderForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
                                    Margin="0,0,47,0"
                                    Background="#FFFBFBFB"
                                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Border x:Name="FirstPickerHost" BorderBrush="#FFFBFBFB">
                                <ComboBox x:Name="HourPicker"
                                          MinWidth="50"
                                          Background="#FFFBFBFB"
                                          FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                                          FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                          FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                                          Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                          Padding="4,0,0,0" />
                            </Border>

                            <Border x:Name="SecondPickerHost" BorderBrush="#FFFBFBFB">
                                <ComboBox x:Name="MinutePicker"
                                          MinWidth="50"
                                          Background="#FFFBFBFB"
                                          FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                                          FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                          FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                                          Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                          Padding="4,0,0,0" />
                            </Border>

                            <Border x:Name="ThirdPickerHost" BorderBrush="#FFFBFBFB">
                                <ComboBox x:Name="PeriodPicker"
                                          MinWidth="50"
                                          Background="#FFFBFBFB"
                                          FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                                          FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                          FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                                          Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                          Padding="0,0,0,0" />
                            </Border>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I would like to use this style, but the formating is messed up, so I'd like to start from a clean copy of the original template

EDIT:
My Visual-Live-Tree
[image]

Comment: In Visual Studio designer, right click the TimePicker control and select "Edit Template" -> "Edit a copy".

Comment: thats not the point, i need find out how to edit the flyout, not the button. but i can't find the flyout design inside the style, also there seems to be no reference to the TimePickerFlyout inside the style.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the **Live Visual Tree** of Visual Studio, we can find that `TimePicker` use `TimePickerFlyoutPresenter` to show it in `PopupRoot`.

[image]

So we can edit its `Style` and `Template` to remove the `Button`s. To find its `Style`, we can search `TimePickerFlyoutPresenter` in **generic.xaml**.

> generic.xaml is available in the (Program Files)\Windows
>   Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.10586.0\Generic
>   folder from a Windows SDK installation.

We can just comment out the `Button`s in its template like following:

```
<Style TargetType="TimePickerFlyoutPresenter">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="242" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="242" />
    <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="398" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumLowBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="TimePickerFlyoutPresenter" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeHighBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource DateTimeFlyoutBorderThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TimePickerFlyoutPresenter">
                <Border x:Name="Background"
                        MaxHeight="398"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel">
                        <!--<Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="45" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>-->

                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="FirstPickerHostColumn" Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="SecondPickerHostColumn" Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ThirdPickerHostColumn" Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Rectangle x:Name="HighlightRect"
                                       Grid.Column="0"
                                       Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                                       Height="44"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       Fill="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}" />

                            <Border x:Name="FirstPickerHost" Grid.Column="0" />
                            <Rectangle x:Name="FirstPickerSpacing"
                                       Grid.Column="1"
                                       Width="2"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       Fill="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                            <Border x:Name="SecondPickerHost" Grid.Column="2" />
                            <Rectangle x:Name="SecondPickerSpacing"
                                       Grid.Column="3"
                                       Width="2"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       Fill="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                            <Border x:Name="ThirdPickerHost" Grid.Column="4" />
                        </Grid>

                        <!--<Grid Grid.Row="1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                       Height="2"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                       Fill="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseLowBrush}" />

                            <Button x:Name="AcceptButton"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    Margin="0,2,0,0"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    Content="&#xE8FB;"
                                    FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                                    FontSize="16"
                                    Style="{StaticResource DateTimePickerFlyoutButtonStyle}" />
                            <Button x:Name="DismissButton"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Margin="0,2,0,0"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    Content="&#xE711;"
                                    FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                                    FontSize="16"
                                    Style="{StaticResource DateTimePickerFlyoutButtonStyle}" />
                        </Grid>-->
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But after this, we can only use <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm the selected time. And customize this control is not easy as we don't know how this is implemented.

To achieve what you want, I'd like to create a new custom control. Here is a blog about [DatePicker calendar custom control for WinRT Xaml](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mim/archive/2013/05/02/datepicker-calendar-custom-control-for-winrt-xaml.aspx). Although this is a DatePicker control, but TimePicker is similar. You can refer to its [source code on Codeplex](http://xamlwinrtcalendar.codeplex.com/) to implement your TimePicker.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, somehow it woks when using the TimePickerFlyoutPresenter-Style inside my StandardStyles.xaml, but I can't find any reference inside the TimePickerStyle and also, as you can see in my edit, no element by the name 'TimePickerFlyoutPresenter'. How does this make sense? It's quiet neccessary for me to understand the behaviour and reference-dependency, since I need to do the same with the DatePicker.

Comment: @Raymond: `TimePickerFlyoutPresenter` is not set in `TimePickerStyle`. When we click or tap on `TimePicker`, it  **popup** `TimePickerFlyoutPresenter` for us to select time. So in **Live Visual Tree**, `TimePickerFlyoutPresenter` is under **`PopupRoot`** not the `TimePicker` control (To see this clearly, we can run the app in simulator). `DatePicker` is similar, we can change the template of `DatePickerFlyoutPresenter` to set its style.

Comment: Tank you so much! I already found the PoputpRoot inside the Visual-Live-Tree, but it was worthless to me untill I used your approach with the simulator.